# I have 3D model ready in Autocad. I would like to color it and extract a 2D png file from it to use

Tags: autocad

I am new to the **AutoDesk AutoCAD** drawing software. I would be really appreciated it if someone could help me out. I will attach the image of the content.

I found 3D drawing from the internet, which is **STP** file extension. I imported the 3D content into AutoCAD. It is a Cessna plane drawing actually. But, the problem is the plane is not colored. How can I **color** it since it has multiple layers on the drawing?

Finally, after the coloring process, I wish to **get png** files from some specific angles to be able to use it in my 2D drawing. How can I manage to do that?

Thank you for your help.

[image: Image of the 3D Cessna Plane]